# Enviar array de checkbox con los marcados y los no marcados

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un formulario con n checkboxes y para saber cuales estan marcados y cuales no necesito tener el array de todos los checkbox tras el submit, por ejemplo:

Tengo 3 checkbox con el mismo name (digo 3 como podrian ser 500 lo decide el usuario (es dinamico))

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="f_numero[]" id="f_numero">
<input type="checkbox" name="f_numero[]" id="f_numero">
<input type="checkbox" name="f_numero[]" id="f_numero">
```

ahora mismo al hacer el submit del formulario si solo hay marcados 2 checkboxes recivo un array de 2:
[1,1]

lo que busco es recibir los 3 checkboxes para asi poder mantener el indice y saber que valor pertenece a que checkbox: [1,0,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías alcanzar todos los checkbox con `querySelectorAll()` y luego verificar los chequeados o no chequeados, guardando la información en un array.

Luego, por el índice del array sabrías a qué elemento pertenece cada estado (`true` o `false`) según esté chequeado o no.

He aquí un ejemplo. He puesto el primer checkbox como chequeado por defecto, para que veas la diferencia. También, he dado ids diferentes a los elementos. W3C Recommendation indica que en el mismo DOM dos elementos no pueden tener el mismo id. Esto podría causar problemas en caso de querer alcanzar esos elementos por su id.

He puesto comentarios in situ, de modo que se entienda lo que hago en cada línea. Si ha duda, pregunta en comentarios. Otra ventaja de este código es que usa Javascript puro, sin dependencia de librerías como jQuery.

```js
/*
  Alcanzamos todos los inputs de tipo checkbox
  Esto se puede refinar si fuera necesario,
  alcazándolos también por clase u otro selector
*/
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
/*
  En el array mResult guardaremos todos los estados,
  true o false si el elemento está chequeado o no
*/
var mResult = [];

/*
  Recorremos todos los checkbox
  verificamos estado y guardamos en mResult
*/
allElements.forEach((v) => {
  mResult.push(v.checked);
});
/*
  Prueba ...
  Por el índice del array podrás saber
  a qué checkbox pertenece cada estado
*/
console.log(mResult);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="f_numero[]" id="f_numero01" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="f_numero[]" id="f_numero02">
<input type="checkbox" name="f_numero[]" id="f_numero03">
```